# 1 dimensional object requires more than 2 cuts

Tags: general-topology, set-partition

Given a string, to break it into 2 pieces, one can simply cut it at any point.

Given a loop, to break it into 2 pieces, there are two cuts needed, as the first cut will make it into a string and the second cut break into 2 pieces.

Then my question is does this pattern continue? Can there be some form of a 1d object such that more than 2 cuts are needed in order to break it into 2 pieces?

Comment: My gut tells me that such a shape exists, but is absolutely hideous. It certainly can't be homeomorphic to a finite graph, as for such objects, two sufficiently close cuts on the interior of an edge always isolate the interval between them.

Comment: Is a *loop* a 1-dimensional object?  It seems like you are assuming that $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ are somehow joined into a loop.  I can relate to mapping (for example) $(0,1)$ to $(-\infty, 0)$ by $f(x) = \log(x)$, so it isn't that much of a stretch for me to visualize mapping a string to $(-\infty, +\infty)$.  However, that still leaves the issue that in $\Bbb{R}, ~-\infty$ and $+\infty$ are not *joined*.

Comment: There are one-dimensional separable metric spaces that are totally disconnected...

Comment: What definition are you using for 1-dimensional here? For example, would two vertices connected by three edges ("strings") count as a one dimensional space (equivalently, a square (boundary only) and one of its diagonals).